# making kohana and nginx work with urls as params that contain .php

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting, kohana

I will begin with the example, I guess it is simpler to understand.

I have a route in kohana that works like mydomain.dev/param

Now this param is an url, a nasty, dirty long url like this one you are viewing currently.

My problem is, that if the url contains .php, like "something.php.net", nginx will tell me that the file does not exist.

Here is my config:

```
  location / {
    expires off;
    try_files  $uri  $uri/  @kohana;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
  }

  location ~/\. {
    deny all;
  }

  location @kohana {
    rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php$request_uri last;
  }

  location ~* \.php {
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param KOHANA_ENV development;

    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }
```

This config works with all static files, etc, but kills the emperor when i get something like mydomain.dev/http://en.php.net. Nginx tells me: File not found.

Can this be solved?

Error log: FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 10.0.0.1, server: laters.dev, request: "GET /ro1.php.net/property_exists

Comment: I thought about replacing any .php to _-_php and handling it from code, but have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

There's thing in regexes called greediness. the beginning of your regex:

```
(.+\.php)
```

Tries to match as many characters before matching the ".php" part. Try modifying it to:

```
(.+?\.php)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer :) Sadly, it did not solve my problem.